# Path from a start point at a certain heading to an end point at a certain heading while obeying a minimum turn radius

Tags: vectors, plane-curves

So not sure if my title is clear (also no idea what to tag, because you need 1000 rep to add tags) so I will try my best to explain the problem.

I'm working in 2D space and to simplify the problem, I'm normalizing headings and locations such that start heading = (1,0) and start position = (0,0).

Given an end point (x,y), a final heading $v$, and a minimum turn radius $r$ is it possible to generate a curved path from start to finish?

What I mean by minimum turn radius is the path cannot turn tighter than the given radius but larger radius turns are possible.

I haven't gotten very far, if at all. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sorry, I am not native english speaker, and cannot understand exactly what you mean by "heading", could you please clarify

Comment: Heading is essentially direction. From Wikipedia: "The direction a person or vehicle is facing, usually similar to its course"

Comment: that's what was intuitively clear, but then , in 2D, the heading shall be a unitary (modulus=1) vector and I edited your post accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You draw a circle of min. radius $r$ tangent to the $x$-axis in the origin, and another passing by $P=(x,y)$ and tangent to $v$. Then you draw a circle, of radius $\ge r$ tangent to both. Choosing the appropriate side when drawing the circles, you can always arrive to a path having the required start and end points and headings.

Comment: Wow, nice answer. Very clear and great constructive solution.

Comment: Glad you appreciate it: it is an "engineering-math" answer

Comment: (Beautiful!)  The circle at each end can be on either side of the tangent line, so in general there are four families of solutions.  (The joining-arc could be longer or shorter.) In what cases, I wonder, must one or more of the four be excluded?

Comment: @AntonSherwood: I do not catch the four solutions that you mention. Apart that of course the joining large-radius arc could be longer or shorter.

Comment: You chose here to make the curvature always counter-clockwise.  For the problem illustrated, you could instead make it clockwise at both ends; the path would then be bigger, but it would not intersect itself.  If it's clockwise at one end and anticlockwise at the other, joining the two circles is more complicated if they overlap; that's a partial answer to my question.

Comment: @AntonSherwood: The matter is that I considered the "headings" in a vectorial sense, so defining a sort of "speed" and thus an outgoing and incoming direction. If considered only as a tangent that can be taken either way then you are right.

Comment: I am not disregarding sense! Flip each circle over its tangent line. The path begins in a clockwise circle, crossing the y axis at -5 rather than +5, then has an upward transition arc on the left, feeding into the second clockwise circle which reaches P in the required direction.  Sorry I don't know how to post an image here.

Comment: @AntonSherwood: now I got your point, makes sense, and would be interesting to examine how many different arrangements there could be. So please post your considerations: click "Add Answer", inside that on the top row you find the icon (that "with mountains "), follow the instructions to load a picture, it's quite simple.